# How to make 2 images responsive at the same time

Tags: html, css, image

I have an html and css code to display 2 images. I'm using bootstrap to make them responsive but only the background is responsive. Could someone tell me why and how to fix it please?

html code:

```
<img id="introducaoBackground" class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/introducaoBackground.png" alt="Background da introdução"></img>
<img id="logo" class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/logo.png" alt="Logo"></img>
```

---

```
#introducaoBackground {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

---

```
#logo {
position: absolute;
top: 73px;
left: 280px;
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of your code. Use the code snippet built into the editor to provide your code. Also, I think you mean "responsive" as opposed to "responsible"?

Comment: What is in "img-fluid" class? By the way add a space between " and src here: "class="img-fluid"src="Imagens/introduca"

Comment: max-width: 100%; and height: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be an absolute logo inside a relative container?

```
<img id="introducaoBackground" class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/introducaoBackground.png" alt="Background da introdução"></img>

<div id="relativeDiv">
  <img id="logo" class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/logo.png alt="Logo"></img>
</div>
```

I have re-used the background attributes for the relativeDiv id but of course you can create different attributes beside position relative.

```
#introducaoBackground {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}

#logo {
position: absolute;
top: 73px;
left: 280px;
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#relativeDiv {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

Another example: 
https://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/tFhkz